# Using annotation on properties yields weak reference error

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeguards

I am trying to consistently use type annotations, but running into an issue with the @property annotation. The code below fails at the print statement with a "cannot create weak reference to 'property' object" error.

```py
from typeguard import typechecked

@typechecked
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    self._p = 1

  @property
  def p(self) -> int:
    return self._p

a = A()
print(a.p)
```

This results in this error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
cannot create weak reference to 'property' object
  File "C:\Code\ExploreSims\scratch.py", line 9, in p
    def p(self) -> int:
  File "C:\Code\ExploreSims\scratch.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(a.p)
          ^^^
TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'property' object
```

If I remove the type annotation, it runs fine. What's happening here? And how do I solve it.

**Edit**

The exact same error occurs in these two cases:

- move the @typechecked annotation to the property itself
- move A to an external file, and import it with install_import_hook

Comment: Sounds like a problem with `typeguard`, not annotations nor properties in general.

Comment: I only see mentions of applying `@typechecked` to ***functions***, not entire classes… https://typeguard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Comment: @deceze Are you shure? The page explicity mentions: `This can also be used as a class decorator.` [typeguard.typechecked](https://typeguard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#typeguard.typechecked)

Comment: @deceze it's valid on a class, the same error occurs when I move it to a property, or when I use install_import_hook. Updated the question.

Comment: Fair enough. I'd still recommend you tag the question appropriately to be about `typeguard`, because that's not a problem with plain classes, is it?

Comment: [This](https://typeguard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features.html#using-typechecked-on-top-of-other-decorators) seems relevant.

Comment: Properties are also tricky because `A.p` is *not* a function that returns an `int`; it's a `property` instance whose `fget` attribute is a function that returns an `int`.

Comment: Decorating the function directly (`@property @typechecked def p(self) -> int: ...`) seems to produce a similar error, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [known and fixed bug](https://github.com/agronholm/typeguard/issues/318) (in `typeguard`), fix released as part of [4.0.0rc1](https://pypi.org/project/typeguard/4.0.0rc1/) on April 2nd 2023.